# How to add underline under selected segment in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to show underline under selected segment.

My html code is :

```
 <ion-segment value="All">
    <ion-segment-button value="All" class="mysegment">
      <ion-label>All</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="Favorite" class="mysegment">
      <ion-label>Favorite</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

My scss code is :

```
 .mysegment {
       color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using **mode="md"** in **ion-segment**, as follow:

```
     <ion-segment value="All" mode="md">
```